# Uniting sequentially a countable set with a "dense barrage"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

consider following setup:
$$ D = \{1-\frac{1}{2^n} |\space n \in {\mathbb N_0}  \} $$

$$ f(x) 
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x \in D$} \\
1, & \text{if $x \in \mathbb N_+$} \\
0, & else
\end{cases}
$$

$$ T_1 := 0\\
 T_n := inf_{t\in(T_{n-1},\infty)}\{f(t) > 0\}
\space \forall \space n \in \{2,3,...\}
$$

Now my question occurs, what will happen if we unite all the $T_n$.
$$ \{{T_n} : {n\in \mathbb N_+}\} =\ ? $$

Comment: Is the infimum maybe supposed to start from $T_{n-1}$?

Comment: Also the way you're defining the $T_n$ each $T_n$ will be a number. Do you really want the union of the numbers? If so how are you representing them Dedekind cuts will give a different result then cauchy sequences.

Comment: Yes it was supposed to start $T_{n-1}$.

Comment: I wanted the $T_{n}$ to be numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry if I took the question out of the context. It erased when I was in probability class. What i actually wanted to do is the following: if $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a right continuous function, where all the left limits exist. Then $f(x_{o}) = lim_{x \to x_{o}^{-0}}(h(x_{o})-h(x))$. With $T_n$ I want to count the uncontinuity spots. I wondered, whether I would find "them all", if uppercase happens.

Comment: No worries you just probably want to union sets containing the $T_n$ or maybe just ask about what $\{T_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ will be. The union you wrote will take the elements **inside** the $T_n$ so will almost certainly not be what you want.